# Assigning null inside the method

Tags: java

So my question is: why assigning at line_2 doesn't affect on the created "test"?
Аlthough line-1 affects.

```
public class Test {
    List list;

    Test() {
        list = new ArrayList();
        someVoid(list);
    }

    void someVoid(List myList) {
        myList.add(0);            // line 1
        myList = null;            // line 2
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.list.size()); // output: 1    , line 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the null value to the reference, not to the object, and once you exit the method that reference is lost (swapped by the Garbage Collector).

Answer (score 1):

Because object are passed as "pointer to that object", so you create a new pointer (in this case `myList`) that points to the same object, and therefore, you have:

```
myList -> actual list of object
```

and when you do `myList = null`, you are assigning `null` to the pointer:

```
myList -> 0x0 // null
```

but the list that it was pointing to, is not been effected

Answer (score 1):

`List` is a reference type, so you are really being passed a reference to the `List`. You can call its methods, but assignment will only change where the reference points to, not the actual object.